# Pimcore : PHP API Asset CRUD failed to open stream error

Tags: php, pimcore

I'm trying to save the image as asset using the below documentation.

I need clarity on 3rd line as to what it does.

I have my image inside web/var/assets folder.
(Is it the right place to keep the image ? Or any1 to explain the code)

I am getting the error like :

> Warning: file_get_contents(myimage1.png): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

https://pimcore.com/docs/5.x/Development_Documentation/Assets/Working_with_PHP_API.html

```
//creating and saving new asset
$newAsset = new Pimcore\Model\Asset();
$newAsset->setFilename("myAsset.png");
$data = file_get_contents('/web/var/assets/products/2_a8.JPG');
$newAsset->setData($data);
$newAsset->setParent(Pimcore\Model\Asset::getByPath("/"));
```

Answer (score 1):

If your image is in web/var/assets folder, it's probably not at myimage1.png

PHP throws a warning because it can not find (and read) the image, the path is wrong.
Your code should probably look like this, if your myimage1.png is in web/var/assets:

`$projectRoot = getenv('PIMCORE_PROJECT_ROOT');
$data = file_get_contents($projectRoot ."/web/var/assets/myimage1.png");
$newAsset->setData($data);`

If the file_get_contents fails, the path is probably wrong. Pimcore is not involved at this stage. Find more about the function in the PHP manual: http://php.net/manual/de/function.file-get-contents.php

Comment: Have updated the answer ..still im getting same error...tried with double quotes too

Comment: I added the pimcore project root to the path, might help. As I said, the path is wrong if you do get the file_get_contents error. Fix the path to the absolute path to your image file.